# Sonos music service: 'No Music' message when playing a program media collection

Tags: sonos

I have a music service added to Sonos in production,

I received a complaint about a user who plays from a calendar of us, and often the music stops and he gets the message 'No Music' in the player. If he presses 'play' again, Sonos continues to play again till the next 'No Music' message.

The problem happens at an element with these properties:

```
<ns1:mediaCollection xsi:type="ns1:mediaCollection" readOnly="true" userContent="false" renameable="false" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <ns1:id>calendar:34685</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>program</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:displayType>List</ns1:displayType>
               <ns1:title>Stylish Restaurant</ns1:title>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>false</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:containsFavorite>false</ns1:containsFavorite>
               <ns1:albumArtURI requiresAuthentication="false">images/menu/green_legacy.png</ns1:albumArtURI>
               <ns1:canAddToFavorite>false</ns1:canAddToFavorite>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
```

The method GetMetadata with calendar:34685 works fine and returns 2 songs, to be responsive on changes in the calendar.

Is it possible that sometimes this request does not return a valid answer? If so, does anyone know which error type or error return code causes this 'no music' message? Or does it return a valid answer without any songs?

Is there a way to see all sent requests and received responses from a sonos controller or sonos device?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is a user specific issue, but you are unable to reproduce, it is possible their home wifi setup could be a possible issue as well.   I would recommend having that user submit a diagnostic report within 20 minutes of it occurring, and then call in to our Customer Support team to see if we can help get more data.

Comment: When we listen to the same calendar, the music also stops sometimes. But it's unpredictable, so we don't know when. So it is not home wifi setup of the customer I guess.

Comment: I notice that you've used `itemType` of `program` for a `mediaCollection`. This is not a valid `itemType` for that `getMetadata` response type. Can you try fixing this? At the same time, if either you or your customer encounters this again, please submit diagnostics, and call our customer care line, who can follow up on the problem.

Comment: Hi, our sonos player stopped playing, when he was playing a calendar of ours. We sent a diagnostics report, with number 7106862.